# Adding an assembly to an SSIS ScriptTask that is not in the GAC?

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to use an assembly in an SSIS Script Task that is not in the GAC.  I know some documentation shows that  [assemblies can only be used if they are stored in the GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136007.aspx), however I also seen some sites that suggest [assemblies that aren't in the  GAC can be used as well](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isn-t-in-the-gac.aspx), however I am unable to to get the recommendations working.

Is it possible to use an assembly in an SSIS Script Task without putting it in the GAC?

The reason I ask is that I am trying to store a C# class in a SQL database.  I want my C# code in my Script Task to then retrieve the class from SQL, compile it, and then use the assembly in a subsequent Script Task in SSIS (we want to maintain a centralized version of the class that is used in many packages).  If there is an alternative solution to this problem that someone can suggest then I would appreciate that as well.  Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing more about your class / requirements, I would first ask why you need C# code to run in a script task. Can you not use a stored procedure to accomplish what the class hopes to achieve?

Comment: @mjw Definitely cannot be accomplished in a stored procedure.  Need to run the C# code in many SSIS solutions and I want to be able to easily update the C# code across all solutions in the future if necessary.

Comment: Have you considered using a web service and web service task? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @mjw that is a good idea that I am considering, however the C# class will be doing heavy processing against millions of records.  It would definitely hit performance to have to send those records over the network to a web service instead of being able to do it locally (I can't host the webservice on the SSIS server).

Comment: Any reason you can't host it on the SQL box? You can take steps to secure it so it's only accessible via localhost.